# Formatting Django forms elements in html templates

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have a contact form that I'm trying to use in one of my Django templates. I created a class for it in forms.py:

```py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email_address = forms.EmailField(max_length=150)
    message = forms.CharField(widget = forms.Textarea,max_length=2000)
```

and added it to my views.py:

```py
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = "Website Inquiry" 
            body = {
            'name': form.cleaned_data['name'], 
            'email': form.cleaned_data['email_address'], 
            'message':form.cleaned_data['message'], 
            }
            message = "\n".join(body.values())

            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@example.com', ['admin@example.com']) 
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect ("BobbleHead:home")
      
    form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, "BobbleHead/contact.html", {'form':form})
```

and am now trying to get the form to render with specific html formatting in my template (contact.html), but am having difficulties.

Previously, I was using the built in Django capabilities to render, like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form.as_p }}
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

That worked fine, but I don't like the way it looks on my webpage and wanted to clean up the formatting. I want the form to render with specific formatting, like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="w3-col m6">
    <form action="/home" target="_blank">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
        <div class="w3-half">
          <div class="fieldWrapper">
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Name" required name="name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-half">
          <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Email" required name="email_address">
        </div>
      </div>
      <input class="w3-input w3-border" type="text" placeholder="Message" required name="message">
      <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

But I'm not sure how to change the `<input>` elements in the stylized block to use my django `form`.

Comment: In your html you are can specific fields of your forms(that you created in forms.py) like this : {{form.name}} , so you can use your own containers to style and just call in the input field from the form, if this is what you are looking for...

Comment: alternatively you can do some designing with crispy forms, here is the doc : https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "w3-input w3-border",
                "type": "text",
                "placeholder": "Name",
                "name": "name",
            }
        ),
        max_length=100
    )
    email_address = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "w3-input w3-border",
                "type": "text",
                "placeholder": "Email",
                "name": "email_address",
            }
        ),
        max_length=150
    )
    message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "w3-input w3-border",
                "type": "text",
                "placeholder": "Message",
                "name": "message",
            }
        ),
        max_length=2000

    )
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="w3-col m6">
  <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
      <div class="w3-half">
        {{ form.name }}
      </div>
      <div class="w3-half">
        {{ form.email_address }}
      </div>
    </div>
    {{  form.message }} 
    <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit">SEND</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `EmailField` default widget is `EmailInput` not `TextInput` and `type` and `name` attribute is by default added, and it will be better if you set max_length as directly inside the field rather than creating as attributes in `attrs` in widget.

Comment: Also by default every field is required see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#required) in docs.

Comment: In the question, you will see that she used `text` for all the inputs, (I know I should use `email` for `EmailField` ! As for the second point, you're right! ;) I update my answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can add attributes (class, name, etc) to django forms using widgets

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'special'}))
    url = forms.URLField()
    comment = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '40'}))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances

and in the template refer directly to the fields using {{form.name}}, {{form.comment}} etc to put them anywhere in the template

Answer (score 0):

You can use form attributes, and define error_messages while defining the form and use in the template in the following way.

forms.py

```py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "w3-input w3-border",
                "placeholder": "Name"
            }
        ),
        error_messages={
         'required':'name is required'
        },
        max_length=100
    )
    email_address = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.EmailInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "w3-input w3-border",
                "placeholder": "Email",
            }
        ),
        error_messages={
        "required":"Email is required"
        },
        max_length=150
    )
    message = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
                "class": "w3-input w3-border",
                "placeholder": "Message",
            }
        ),
        error_messages={
        'required':'Message is required'
        },
        max_length=2000
    )
```

Template file:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<div class="w3-col m6">
    <form action="/home" target="_blank">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="w3-row-padding" style="margin:0 -16px 8px -16px">
        <div class="w3-half">
          <div class="fieldWrapper">
          {{form.name}}
          {% for error in form.name.errors %}
             {{error|striptags}}
          {% endfor %}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-half">
          {{form.email}}
          {% for error in form.email.errors %}
            {{error|striptags}}
          {% endfor %}

        </div>
      </div>
      {{form.message}}
      {% for error in form.message.errors %}
      {{error|striptags}}
      {% endfor %}
      
      <button class="w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right" type="submit">SEND</button>
    </form>
  </div>
```

The views.py can be remain same, you can also specify other attributes like help_texts etc.

See all [`form fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/) of django.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more granular control over the form rendering (such as changing the size of the input area or keeping previous values in the field when updating a form) do checkout this link: https://www.webforefront.com/django/formtemplatelayout.html

The template looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.non_field_errors }}

  <div class="fieldWrapper">
    <h5>Field1</h5>
    {{ form.Field1.errors }}  // To render any error messages
    {{ form.Field1 }}  // If you want the form field as default
  </div>
  
  <div class="fieldWrapper">
    <h5>Field2</h5>
    {{ form.Field2.errors }}  
    <input value="{{ <model.field> }}" type="text" name="Field2" size="10">  // If you want to be able to change the size or would like to keep the last updated value in the text field (where name="<your_form_field_name>") 
  </div>

<button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```